# using half identities to find exact value of each trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

a) $\cos{({105}^{°})}$

b) $\sin{(\frac{3\pi}{8})}$

c) $\cot{({67.5}^{°})}$

please do explain how you are able to get the answer as I'm still confused about this topic... Thank you

Comment: Hint: If you double each of those angles you will get angles that have simple trig ratios. Eg $2 \times 105° = 210° = 180°+30°$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, $$\cos 105^\circ=\cos(90^\circ+15^\circ)=-\sin 15^\circ=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos 30^\circ}{2}}=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}}{2}}=-\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt 3}{4}}$$ $$=-\sqrt{\frac{4-2\sqrt 3}{8}}= -\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}=\frac{1-\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}$$ $$\implies \sin\frac{3\pi}{8}=\sin 67.5^\circ=\sin(90^\circ-22.5^\circ)=\cos 22.5^\circ=-\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos 45^\circ}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 2+1}{2\sqrt 2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}}{2}$$

$$\implies \cot 67.5^\circ=\sqrt{\csc^267.5-1}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sin^2 67.5^\circ}-1}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}}\right)^2-1}=\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt2}{2+\sqrt 2}}=\sqrt{\frac{(2-\sqrt2)^2}{4-2}}=\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{\sqrt2}=\sqrt 2-1$$

Thus, we have all the values as follows $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\cos 105^\circ=\frac{1-\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}}}$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\sin \frac{3\pi}{8}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}{2}}}$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\cot 67.5^\circ=\sqrt 2-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

For the first one you just need the compound angle identity, i.e. $\cos(60 +45)$

For the second one, use $\sin^2x=\frac 12(1-\cos2x)$

For the third one, try $\csc2x+\cot2x=\cot x$

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$
$$\cot A=\dfrac{\cos A}{\sin A}=\dfrac{2\cos^2A}{2\cos A\sin A}=\dfrac{1+\cos2A}{\sin2A}$$

or $$\cot A=\cdots=\dfrac{\sin2A}{1-\cos2A}$$

---

$(2)$
$$\cos2B=2\cos^2B-1=1-2\sin^2B$$

$$\cos^2B=\dfrac{1+\cos2B}2,\cos B=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos2B}2}$$

Now use [All Sin Tan Cos Rule](http://www.mathymind.com/all-sin-tan-cos-rule-in-trigonometry/)